# Blank screen displayed when I added container widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to display the second screen when the button is pressed on the first screen. For that, I am using navigation.push. That works fine until I add a container widget inside the row widget in my Second screen layout. When I remove that it works fine. Can Anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?
This is the code of my second screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 60.0),
        child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
           
             ClipRRect(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200.0),
                 child: Image.asset(
                   'assets/images/test.png',
                   height: 200.0,
                   width: 200.0,)
             ),


             SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
             Text(
               'Remote User',
               style: TextStyle(
                   color: Colors.black,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                   fontSize: 25),
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
             Text(
               'Incoming Call',
               style: TextStyle(
                   color: Colors.black,
                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                   fontSize: 15),
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 120.0,),
             
             Row(
               children: <Widget>[
               //when I add single container it works fine
                 Container(
                   height: 70.0,
                   width: 70.0,
                   child: FittedBox(
                     child: FloatingActionButton(
                       onPressed: () {},
                       elevation: 20.0,
                       //shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                       mini: false,
                       child: Icon(
                         Icons.call,
                         color: Colors.white,
                       ),
                       backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
                 // this widget cause blank screen
                 Container(
                   height: 70.0,
                   width: 70.0,
                   child: FittedBox(
                     child: FloatingActionButton(
                       onPressed: () {},
                       elevation: 20.0,
                       //shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                       mini: false,
                       child: Icon(
                         Icons.call,
                         color: Colors.white,
                       ),
                       backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
        ]
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the code of First screen:

```
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Second Screen'),
          onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()),);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone facing the same issue please visit this post it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54017447/more-than-one-floating-action-button-on-same-screen-displays-black-screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, remove the left and right padding in Line-9

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 60.0, left: 400.0, right: 400.0),
```

You are facing this problem because you are adding two Floating action buttons in one screen

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class NewScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   body: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 60.0),
    child: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
       
         ClipRRect(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200.0),
             child: Image.asset(
               'assets/images/test.png',
               height: 200.0,
               width: 200.0,)
         ),


         SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
         Text(
           'Remote User',
           style: TextStyle(
               color: Colors.black,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
               fontSize: 25),
         ),
         SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
         Text(
           'Incoming Call',
           style: TextStyle(
               color: Colors.black,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
               fontSize: 15),
         ),
         SizedBox(height: 120.0,),
         
         Row(
           children: <Widget>[

           //when I add single container it works fine
           //EDITED PART

             Container(
               height: 70.0,
               width: 70.0,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: Colors.green,
                 shape: BoxShape.circle
               ),
               child: GestureDetector(
                 onTap: () {},
                 //shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                //  mini: false,
                 child: Icon(
                   Icons.call,
                   color: Colors.white,
                 ),
                //  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
               ),
             ),

             // this widget cause blank screen
             //EDITED PART

             Container(
               height: 70.0,
               width: 70.0,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 color: Colors.green,
                 shape: BoxShape.circle
               ),
               child: GestureDetector(
                 onTap: () {},
                 //shape: CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red)),
                //  mini: false,
                 child: Icon(
                   Icons.call,
                   color: Colors.white,
                 ),
                //  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
               ),
             ),
           ],
         ),
       ]
     ),
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

It may help you

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it stil does not work. Its works when I display it directly from main.dart. But when I push it from my first screen this issue occurs

Comment: I think you are facing this problem because you are adding two floating action buttons in one screen. Let me correct this for you.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for giving me direction bro. You were right this was because of using two floating buttons. When it set the value for "HeroTag" to null it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Some unwanted padding is there, like

```
left: 400.0, right: 400.0
```

mentioned proper ones, removing those you can see your widgets, try below code

```
padding:
        EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 60.0),
```

Comment: Thanks for answering :). I removed the padding but still it does not work. It only works when I remove the second widget.

Comment: restart the application.

Comment: I did that but same result. It displays correctly when i use it in main.dart. But when I launch it from firstscreen.dart using Navigation.push this happens